# Sylius installation doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sylius

I have a problem with the installation of Sylius.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 126
```

This error occur when I run : `composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius-standard Club26`

My configuration is :

- Wamp on Win7 64bits (for Apache, PHP and MySQL)
- I have git installed
- I use cmder to run my command
- I have changed `memory_limit = 1024M in php.ini`
- I tried with composer install with Windows Setup, and with composer.phar

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you sure you have changed it in the correct php.ini? Try `php -i` and check which configuration file is loaded by your PHP installation - it just might be different...

Comment: @RobertRossmann afaik, Composer overrides the value itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [disabling Garbage Collection](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/blog/composer-gc-performance-who-is-affected-too) during installation.

For global installations of Composer

```
$ php -d zend.enable_gc=0 `which composer` create-project -s dev sylius/sylius-standard Club26
```

For local installation of composer.phar

```
$ php -d zend.enable_gc=0 composer.phar create-project -s dev sylius/sylius-standard Club26
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, I got also memory error during the execution of sylius:install
I set memory_limit to -1 to fix it

```
$ php -d memory_limit=-1 app/console sylius:install
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this tips